# Cannot get argument with Commanderjs

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm trying to pass a command line argument through node like so: `npm start -s config.yml`, where `npm start` maps to `node app.js` in my `package.json`.

`app.js` is as follows:

```
const program = require('commander');

console.log(process.argv);

program
    .command('-s, --shell <value>', '.yml config file')
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log(program.shell);
```

the argument is being passed through `process.argv`, but when I log `program.shell` it comes back undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `command` as if its an option field. Maybe the library cannot support a command starting with "-". Also looks like you have to attach an action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following:

```
$ node runme.js shell aceofspades
```

On the following file:

```
// FILE: runme.js
const program = require('commander');

program
  .command('shell [value]', '.yml config file')
  .action((cmd, opt) => {
    console.log('cmd:', cmd);   // shell
    console.log('opt:', opt);   // aceofspades
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Gives me the command and arguments within the action function for the command.